# `slug` is not updated when update referenced column with friendly_id 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I want to update `slug` column when `screen_name` is updated, so I write like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :screen_name, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || screen_name_changed?
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do to make it work?
I'm using `rails 4.0.2` and `friendly_id 5.0.2`.

And `slug` is properly generated when a user is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to write as a comment, but it will be clearer here

We have the exact same code working in one of our apps:

```
#Slug
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
end
```

The only thing I would suggest is to post your logs for when you update a `user`?

Comment: Sorry, when I tried to recreate the problem, it disappeared somehow. Thanks for your answer anyway.